# Show that there are no positive integer solutions to $x^2 + x + 1 = y^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I'm trying to prove that

$$x^2 + x + 1 = y^2$$

has no integer solution. So far I've tried proof by contradiction, but all of that seems to rely on me being able to factor this expression into some neat form where the solution is obvious. I've not been able to do so.

Comment: Hint: show that $x^2+x+1$ always lies between two consecutive integer squares when $x$ is a positive integer.

Comment: Try using $(y-x)(y+x)=x+1$ and showing this can't be.

Comment: These seem like interesting ways to think about it that I hadn't considered. I'm not sure how to prove yours, @MarkBennet but the second solution gets me a little closer. I still don't know how I could use that to preclude $x$ and $y$ from being integers after I'd assumed such, though.

Comment: What is $(x+1)^2$?

Comment: I can see that it's $x^2 + 2x + 1$, which is greater than the assumed perfect square $y^2$. But I don't see how I can prove that whatever value it IS equal to must be less than  $(y+1)^2$.

Comment: Observe that if $x \in \mathbb{N}$, then $x^2 < x^2 + x + 1 < x^2 + 2x + 1 = (x + 1)^2$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I see now! That makes it far clearer. I think what was confusing me was the presence of the $y^2$. But I can see how we could safely not need to consider it in this proof.

Comment: So the equation has the form.  $$ax^2+bx+1=y^2$$  Will be infinitely many solutions if the $a$ is not a square.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by multiplying both sides by $4$.

$$4y^2=4x^2+4x+4$$
$$(2y)^2=(2x+1)^2+3$$
$$(2y)^2-(2x+1)^2=3$$

The only $2$ squares whose difference is $3$ are $4$ and $1$.  So $2x+1=\pm1$, which has no positive solution.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

If $n$ is square then $n\equiv 1,4,0 (\mod 8) $.

In your case $y$ is an **odd number** then $$y^2\equiv 1(\mod 8)$$ and

$$
x^2<y^2<x^2+2x+1
$$

Now it 's easy to conclude.

Answer (score 1):

You could try completing the square to obtain $(x+\frac{1}{2})^2 + 1 - \frac{1}{4} = y^2 $. So if there exist integer solutions to this equation, then $(x+\frac{1}{2})^2 + 1 - \frac{1}{4}$ is a perfect square. Go from here to reach a contradiction.

Comment: I can't see how thinking about it this way is any easier. "So if there exist integer solutions to this equation, then $(x+0.5)^2+1−0.25$ is a perfect square..." to me, that just simplifies to exactly the problem I was starting with.

Comment: Well, $(x+\frac{1}{2})^2$ is a square and $\frac{3}{4}$ is not.

Comment: So then I'd only need to prove that the sum of a perfect square and a non-perfect square could not be a perfect square. Hmmm...

Answer (score 0):

your statement can be  written as 
for all x,y in Z^+ such that (x^2+x+1 is not equal to y^2) 
Negation of this statement should be 
Assume there exists x,y in Z^+ (x^2+x+1=y^2)
Three situations can arise 
1. x=y 
then factorize above equation as (y-x)(y+x)=x+1 
since x=y therefore 0=x+1 => x=-1 which contradicts our assumption.
2. x>y 
then factorize above equation as (y-x)(y+x)=x+1
since x>y therefore l.h.s = negative while R.h.s is positive which contradicts our assumption. 
3. xx+1 we  can also say that (y-x)(y+x)>x+1 which also contradicts our third condition. So our proposition is true.

Comment: from 3 condition

Comment: Kindly see this now , I was in hurry when I was answering .....

Answer (score 0):

> $x^2 + x + 1 = y^2$ has no positive integer solutions.

Assume that $x$ and $y$ are positive:  then
$$x^2 - y^2 = -(x+1)$$ 
Therefore,
$$(x-y)(x+y) = -(x+1)$$ ($x$ is positive so the right hand side is positive)

1. this implies $x >  y$

   $x= m + y$ ((m some positive integer))

$(y + m)^2 + y + m = y^2$ ((contradiction))

then $x < y$ which implies that there is contradiction, 
so our statement is true.